# Where to add an optional 'Title' or 'Subject' input?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, email, discovery

I have a website, that users send messages to the staff (similar to support tickets). I want the users to be able to add a `title` or `subject` to the message.

Most of the users (90%), will not use it. They don't have to do it, and we don't need the title and subject.

But for some users (maybe 10%), it will help them to find the message in the future, by see the title & subject instead of snippet.

I don't want the regular users will think that they have to add a subject. I don't want the users to spend time by thinking about the subject.
But I want that some users, who need it, will have the option to add a `subject`

What's a good way to add this feature?

[image]

More info:

- [English Review](https://englishreview.net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Add a discrete link in a secondary focus area (top right)

This is how Gmail managed to remove the CC and BCC fields from their compose window.

[image]

In your case it might look something like this:

[image]

**The location and wording communicate that this is not a critical element of the process, yet at the same time, if a user was to think "How can I add a subject/title to this message?", the answer is discoverable.**

When the user clicks, a field with appropriately instructive placeholder text could appear above the message input.

You might want to include a way (maybe a 'cancel' or 'remove' link) of backing out, or removing the field, but you should be ok as long as the optional aspect is clearly communicated, and in any case, this is the kind of thing you should test with users.

[image]

Comment: I like the link on the right. It's looks good. Any people will not miss it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the suggestion @denislees offers makes sense.

Also, by way of another example, below is how reddit (who require a title, but text in the message body is optional) does it:

[image]